# OpenCL 24-bit mul_hi built-in function

Tags: opencl, long-integer, unsigned-integer

I use my GPU to perform lots of integer arithmetic. `mul24()` and `mad24()` are very helpful to get significant integer performance boosts. Sadly, some of my kernels needs more than 24-bit integers, forcing me to use compiler generated code, which is not always optimal. If I could access hardware instruction equivalent to `mul_hi()` but for 24-bit integers, name it `mul24_hi()`, I would get better performance from my GPUs.

Is there any equivalent to `mul_hi()` but for 24-bit integers or any pattern/idiom/workaround to reliably instruct the compiler to emit it?

Comment: At least for AMD GCN GPUs, such an instruction definitely exists (V_MUL_HI_U32_U24 for uints), although I haven't seen any solutions on how to cause it to be generated, e.g. https://community.amd.com/thread/159845 - Have you tried the "obvious", i.e. performing ulong multiplication with explicitly truncated source operands? e.g. `ulong result48 = (ulong)(0xffffff & a) * (0xffffff & b);` Clang and GCC for CPUs tend to recognise this sort of pattern for generating 32-bit multiplication ops and getting 64-bit results, for example. I'm wondering if e.g. LLVM will do the same for 24->48bit muls.

Comment: @pmdj I have an AMD GCN GPU. Definitively the compiler is recognizing the suggested pattern, but is not emitting desired instructions. I know it is recognizing it because if I ask for the high 32-bit word of the multiplication when I mask operand with `0xFFFF` it becomes a noop. But when I mask them with `0xFFFFFF` it emits 32-bit `mul_hi()`, not 24-bit one.

Comment: Damn. Try contacting AMD about this directly, I hear they're pretty good at responding.

Comment: FP cores can't be emulated for this? Are they idle?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't understand the question, but yes, all my use cases of integer GPU capabilities don't use floating-point at all.

Comment: @user3368561 I mean convert ints to floats, do all operations on floats, then convert back to ints. Conversion is slow so it may need a lot of operations to be offloaded. But not sure if both int and float units can be fed by remaining bandwidth.